# Php, Html selected Issue

Tags: php, html

Following is my Php code where all country come from mysql database. It's a user profile area where users can update their country name. But it's not **selected** (html selected = selected) after he submit his country name.
May be it's my **$sel** variable problem. Can some one fix it ?

```
<select name="country" class="country"> 
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select * from country");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id=$row['Code'];
$data=$row['Name'];

    if($data == $country2)
    {
        $sel = 'selected = "selected"';
    }
    else
    {
        $sel = "";
    }

echo '<option value="'.$id.'" $sel>'.$data.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables are not parsed inside of single quotes. You use concatenation for the other variables in your statement, but not $sel...

```
echo '<option value="'.$id.'"' . $sel . '>'.$data.'</option>';
```

Or switch to double quotes..

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:-

```
<select name="country" class="country"> 
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select * from country");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id=$row['Code'];
$data=$row['Name'];

    if($data == $country2)
    {
        $sel = 'selected = "selected"';
    }
    else
    {
        $sel = "";
    }

echo '<option value="'.$id.'"' . $sel . '>'.$data.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, strings in single quotes will not have the variables in their content parsed. `$sel` will therefore be printed just like that. Either use `$sel` separately (`'<option value="'.$id.'" '.$sel.'>'`) or use double quotes (`"<option value=\"$id\" $sel>"`).